# Can auto transfer data from memcached to mysql DB?

Tags: python, mysql, django, memcached

I'm building a real-time service so my real-time database need to storage in memcached before fetch to DB (Avoid to read/write mysql db too much). I want to fetch data to mysql DB when some events occur , etc : before data expire or have least-recently-used (LRU) data. What is solution for my problem ? My system used memcached , mysql ,django and python-memcache 
Thank

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? I'm not sure what you mean by “I want to fetch data to mysql DB when some events occur”.

Comment: Sorry for my terrible english , It's mean that i want a solution to check data in memcached for moving them automatically to mysql db before they're expire , or move the least-recently-used data when memory is full. Is cronjob a good choice ?

Comment: Have you tested that mysql inserts are too slow for you task?  If they are, python may be a bad choice as well -- it's interpreted and therefore slow and garbage collector can interrupt execution any moment.

Comment: @Nguyen: Ah, that makes sense. In that case, @MarkR is correct: storing data in memcached is likely a bad idea. Are you sure that's an acceptable solution?

Comment: @Alex really? I was under the impression that the nature of Python's GC made it fairly predicable… Can you point me to documentation talking about problems it has caused?

Comment: @David It's predictable, true. Still, it takes 50-150ms on my machine (measured with `timeit.timeit("gc.collect()",1)`) which is too bad for typical real-time app and also longer than typical wait on correctly optimized mysql write.

Comment: @Alex Ah, fair enough. And “correctly optimized”, yes. However, I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that, possibly, if the OP is having trouble with writes being too slow, there's a better chance it's because they aren't correctly optimized than because of the volume…

Answer (score 1):

Memcached is not a persistent store, so if you need your data to be durable *at all* then you will need to store them in a persistent store immediately.

So you need to put them somewhere - possibly a MySQL table - as soon as the data arrive, and make sure they are fsync'd to disc. Storing them in memcached as well only speeds up access, so it is a nice to have.

Memcached can discard any objects at any time for any reason, not just when they expire.